# Fastest Algorithms for Determining the Nullity of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How exactly does one go about determining the Nullity of a Matrix quicker than simply running Gaussian Elimination on the matrix itself?

To be perfectly honest I can't think of a method that doesn't break down to Gaussian Elimination?

Is there some way of using Matrix Inversions, Determinants, and Matrix Multiplications to figure out the Nullity?

Comment: Matrix inversion and determinant also uses Gaussian elimination. I bet that is the fastest.

Comment: @Berci I am afraid you'd lose your bet. Gaussian elimination is $O(n^3)$. Williams algorithm is $O(n^{2.373})$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra

Comment: Due to rounding errors, methods like pivoted QR factorization or SVD are more suitable for determining rank/nullity.

Comment: @user58697 I was hoping there was some technique for determining the nullity quickly along those lines. I am going to cross-post this on cstheory.stackexchange and see what I can gather from there